# How to transfer a variable from table cell class to another view through button

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Parse and Swift.  I have a news feed with posts and each post has an ID.  I have a variable that shows the current post ID.  I have Navigation views set up in storyboard and when you push a comment button on a post it goes to the comments view.

I have functions set up to get the comments and the only thing I don't have access to is the post ID. All of the questions I find on here say to do an override func to pass the variable to the new view controller, but it doesn't work within the table cell and that is the only place I have access to the post ID.  It works to transfer a variable from one `UIViewController` to another but I need to pass it from the Table View Cell class.

From what I have read you can only pass a "tag" through a button which I think has to be Int, and my ID is a string and always has letters and numbers.   I hope this was specific enough, please let me know if I have to include any other information. I have spent several days trying to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a UITableViewController? Its easy to link a cell to the item it is representing with a reference to the UITableViewDatasource's.

`func indexPathForCell(cell: UITableViewCell) -> NSIndexPath?`

If it is a button in a cell find out what the button's superview is, ,Usually the cell's but you can keep going up until you find a UITableViewCell subclass, and then use the cell to find the indexPath.

A helper function on the Datasource to get the data for cell's indexPath may also be required

Comment: I'm not good enough to do all that, but basically I went to the datasource and assigned the ID within the datasource to the view controller.  Then I used the override func to pass the ID through segue to comments view controller.  This probably isn't the right way to do it but it works and I just need to get this app done and out there as fast as I can.  Could you tell me if there is anything wrong with this method?

Comment: Basically whenever the ID changes (as the user scrolls through news feed) the variable in the news feed view controller changes with it.  Then if the comment button is pressed, it is passed through the segue to the comments page.  Hope I explained it clear enough haha

Comment: Yep That segue function could be where you need to use the methods described in my answer, The sender is probably your button, you can find the data through that button as described and then send the data (ID String or the object itself) to the ViewController

Comment: is my way okay though?

Comment: I'm starting to understand your answer more.  You are saying I can get the index of the cell and use that to get the data in the new viewcontroller so I actually kind of understand now.  I veered off and did some other stuff in my app and now i'm back to working on this, and have a little bit more knowledge of swift and xcode.  I think if I can get the index i'll be able to do this but not sure where to put that function that you said earlier.